# Android notification vibration issues

Tags: android

I seem to be unable to change the pattern/length of vibrations using set.Vibrate. My code is as follows:

```
     NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "expired")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.emptylove_icon)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_expired_title))
                .setContentText(notestring + getString(R.string.notification_expired_text))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

This successfully delivers notifications with correct icons, colors, and there is a simple short vibration.

However, any variation of

```
setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000})
```

results in the same vibration no matter what values I put in. Whatever I do the vibration stays the same. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you try only giving 2 parameters like this setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000})?

Comment: @PrashanthVerma I tried  setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000}) and also  setVibrate(new long[] { 5000, 5000}) but both resulted in the same default vibration. It's like it ignores setVibrate